# How do you specify the tag name for sproutcore/emberjs inline script templates?

Tags: ember.js, sproutcore

Ember inline templates are wrapped in DIVs. I'd like to wrap them with a different tag. How do I do that?

The following template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
Foo
</script>
```

generates something like:

```
<div>Foo</div>
```

I'd like to generate something like:

```
<someOtherTag>Foo</someOtherTag>
```

Comment: Excellent question! The workaround suggested in the answer is clearly a very poor situation to be forced into, since it makes the developer move a presentation decision — about what tag should appear in the HTML — *out* of the template where all other HTML tags live (!) and into his JavaScript code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that is possible in the current version 0.9.3 . If you look at https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-views/lib/views/view.js#L707 `div` is used when the property `tagName` is not set.

You could define your own `Ember.View` and set the tagName but I guess you want to achieve this without creating your own view class.

**UPDATE**

I found a way via specifying your custom view as `data-view` attribute on the script element.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        App = Ember.Application.create({});
        App.View = Ember.View.extend({
            tagName: 'someOtherTag'
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-view="App.View" >
        Foo
    </script>
</body>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/9F7kR/2/

Comment: Thanks. I like your workaround. The culprit seems to be in Ember.Handlebars.bootstrap - it creates a Ember.View with just the default tags :-(

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/loader.js#L56

Comment: I've added a pull request which adds support for a data-tag-name attribute on the script tag. https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/299

Comment: The pull request has been merged into the master branch, so the next release of ember contains my addition.

Comment: The data-tag-name addition has been removed since it gives the script tag too much "power". Specifying the tag name should really be set in a custom `Ember.View`, as described in the answer. See discussion of the remove here: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/1112

Comment: Never mind. I've given up on Ember in favor of KnockoutJS. It gives me more control of the generated HTML.

Comment: The removal of the feature is quite unfortunate -- the ability to set `tagName` in the `<script>` tag greatly simplifies one-off, example applications...