# <script type="x-text/handlebars" always becomes an 'ember-view' as a div - how to make it a span?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Looking at this JS:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.AView = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'span',
    firstName: 'Joe',
    surname: 'Bloggs'
});
```

and this HTML:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#view App.AView}}{{firstName}}{{/view}}
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#view App.AView}}{{surname}}{{/view}}
</script>
```

when rendered (as demonstrated in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r9svv/3/) displays:

```
Joe
Bloggs
```

I want them to appear on the same line, i.e. the '`<script text="text/x-handlebars">`' is becoming an ember view, and I need to set it to a 'span' rather than a 'div'.  How do I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify `data-tag-name` on the `<script>` tag:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-tag-name="span">
    {{#view App.AView}}{{firstName}}{{/view}}
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-tag-name="span">
    {{#view App.AView}}{{surname}}{{/view}}
</script>
```

Comment: Actually, this feature has been removed, see this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629287/how-do-you-specify-the-tag-name-for-sproutcore-emberjs-inline-script-templates#comment14946627_8629391

Answer (score 0):

is it:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#view App.AView}}{{firstName}} {{surname}}{{/view}}
</script>
```

that you are looking for?

Comment: No, the real world usage is structured like the original example, the example was just simplified for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

This tells ember to make an outer anonymous view with a nested inner AView.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#view App.AView}}{{firstName}}{{/view}}
</script>
```

EDIT: You can change the tag name of such anonymous views. See below.

To ge the desired behaviour, I would avoid the outer anonymous by using named view templates. I'd create two views working off the same model. Here's an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/algesten/v8WD2/2/

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.model = Ember.Object.create({ // move data to model object
    firstName: 'Joe',
    surname: 'Bloggs'
});

App.AView = Ember.View.extend({ // make two named views
    tagName: 'span',
    templateName: 'first',
    model: App.model
});
App.BView = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'span',
    templateName: 'last',
    model: App.model
});

// append the views
$(function() {
    App.AView.create().append();
    App.BView.create().append();
});
```

And the handlebars:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="first">
    {{model.firstName}}
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="last">
    {{model.surname}}
</script>
```

EDIT: As pointed out by ebryn. The tag name can be changed on anonymous views.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-tag-name="span">
    {{#view App.AView}}{{firstName}}{{/view}}
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-tag-name="span">
    {{#view App.AView}}{{surname}}{{/view}}
</script>
```

Comment: But how do I insert the views in the correct place in the DOM?  I can't believe the ember.js implementation of handlebars could be so inflexible.

Comment: The `.append()` method takes a jQuery style selector. Example `.append('#mydiv')`